# Multiple state transition probabilities in Markov model

Tags: r, probability, mathematical-statistics

I have a problem where, in a multi-state Markov model with monthly timesteps, I have a state X where, in an average of 1 year, individuals exit from the state in this proportion:

- 56% of individuals go to state A
- 43% of the remaining individuals that don't go to A go to state Y
- 57% of the remaining individuals that don't go to A
  go to state Z

I'm trying to figure out constant transition probabilities so these conditions can be met, but can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. Thank you!

Comment: There is no unique answer to the question. The probabilities in time follow some probability distribution function (pdf). Even if we knew what that pdf was, the answer would depend on what the parameter values for that pdf were.

Comment: Did you mean "43% of the remaining individuals that don't go to *A* go to state Y"?
Are these percentages what you observe *after* 12 transitions, or the probabilities estimated from 12 transitions?

Comment: Yes, apologies, it is 43% who do not go to state A go to state Y.